# Does the collection of all finite subsets of the real numbers have the Finite Intersection Property?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

**Does F, the collection of all finite subsets of the real numbers, have the finite intersection property?**

I'm not sure how to approach this questions but my intuition tells me that F does not have the finite intersection property. So if one set is {1, 2, 3, 4} and another set is {5, 6, 7, 8} the intersection of these 2 sets would be empty thus F does not have the FIP. Is this logic right?

Also, I am trying to figure out:

**Does G, the collection of complements of the subsets in F (the collection of all co-finite subsets of R), have the finite intersection property?**

It makes sense to me that the intersection of co-finite subsets would be non-empty because all of the sets would be "bounded" by negative infinity and positive infinity if that makes sense.. but I don't know how to explain or prove that logically.

Comment: Hint: the empty subset is in particular a finite subset of the real numbers.

Comment: @MeesdeVries so F doesn't have the FIP since any set intersect with the empty set is empty?

Comment: Can you define the *finite intersection property* you have in mind?

Comment: You're right that $F$ does not have the finite intersection property.  Showing that $G$ does have it is more interesting.  Hint: You are working with complements and intersections, so recall De Morgan's law.  (Your current plan might lead you astray: the collection of all *unbounded* sets does not have the finite intersection property.  Consider the set of integers and the set of non-integers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As smartly pointed out in the comments, it is trivial to show that $F$ does not have the $FIP$.

Now what about $G$? Let us assume that $G$ does not have the $FIP$ and arrive at a contradiction:

If $G$ does not have the $FIP$ then there is a finite $G' \subset G $ for which

$$\bigcap_{g \in G'} g = \emptyset$$

But given that $G$ is composed of the complements of sets in $F$, we get: $\forall g\in G'\ \ \exists f_g\in F:\ g = \mathbb{R} - f_g$

Rewriting the intersection, you get

$$\bigcap_{g \in G'} (\mathbb{R} - f_g) = \emptyset$$

Now if there is no number $x$ that appears in all $g$ then for every number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is some $g_x$ such that $x \notin g_x \iff x \notin (\mathbb{R} - f_{g_x}) \iff x \in f_{g_x}$. But since that is true for **any** $x$, then all the real numbers are in a finite union of finite sets, which is itself finite! So we would be proving that $\mathbb{R}$ is finite. But we know that $\mathbb{R}$ isn't finite so we arrived at a contradition and therefore $G$ has the $FIP$.